# Executing Expect command with ansible is not outputing anything

Tags: ansible, expect

I can access the remote server without problem and I would  like to send `bwcli` command which is a CLI of Broadworks server. I am using a shell code to send the command.

Normally if i want to enter the cli I type `bwcli` but it is not recognized when doing it remotely so I am sendig this `sudo -u bworks /usr/local/broadworks/bw_base/bin/bwcli`

instead like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/expect

expect ":"

send "sudo -u bworks /usr/local/broadworks/bw_base/bin/bwcli\r"

expect ">"

send "?\r"

expect "AS_CLI>"
```

My playbook is done like this:

```
 -script: /home/ansible/playbooks/David/get_command.sh >> bwcli_login.log
```

When the playbook is ran it shows `OK=1 changed=1 unreachable=0 failed=0`.
So I am assuming that it  works,but when I go to open "bwcli_login.log" I find it empty.
This is only my first step in the code I would like when I enter the CLI the I send some other commands to retrieve some information for the server. And it is annoying that I am stuck at the first step :(
I appreciate if somebody can tell me why the file output file is empty? What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Is it works when you manually run the script on the remote server without ansible ?

You can execute a script with different user without using `sudo su <username>` in your script, also check/share the output from ansible with `stdout_lines`, it will be easier to debug.

script:

```
#! /usr/bin/expect
expect ":"
send "/usr/local/broadworks/bw_base/bin/bwcli\r"
expect ">"
send "?\r"
expect "AS_CLI>"
```

ansible:

```
- name: run script
  script: /home/ansible/playbooks/David/get_command.sh
  become: yes
  become_user: bworks
  register: out

- debug: var=out.stdout_lines
```

Have you tried to use `ansible expect_module` ?

I am not famialer with `BroadWorks` at all, but maybe you can try to do something like the below example.

You will need:

The command module takes command to run,

responses - Mapping of expected string/regex and string to respond with. If the response is a list, successive matches return successive responses.

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/expect_module.html

I am not sure if the below example it is what you need or if it will work, just something to work with.

```
- name: expect test
   expect: 
     command: /usr/local/broadworks/bw_base/bin/bwcli
     response:
       '>': "?\r"
```

Comment: Hi Berlin, thanks for your  feedback. I have followed your suggestion and I get:[ ok: [AS_2] => {
    "changed": false, 
    "out.stdout_lines": [
        "", 
        "Your password will expire in 762 day(s).", 
        "/usr/local/broadworks/bw_base/bin/bwcli"
    ]
}

Comment: I am not sure what else you should see, but now you can see the output of your script.

Comment: I have added a code to the playbook  se what I am sending and I get this: Your password will expire in 762 day(s).
/usr/local/broadworks/bw_base/bin/bwcli^M

Comment: But when I added extra commands in my expect script to go in a specific directory :
send "cd /Monitoring/Report\r"

expect ">"

send "current\r"

Comment: and when I send a command "current"  to get server server statistics I do not get anything. I have checked what I am sending and this is what I am sending: /usr/local/broadworks/bw_base/bin/bwcli^Mcd /Monitoring/Report^Mcurrent^M

Comment: I can help you only with ansible, but I am not sure if this issue coming from ansible

Comment: This is my playbook for saving output file, where I see only the command above I sent but not server report:- name: "save out"
    local_action:
      copy content="{{ out.stdout }}" dest="/root/out.log"

Comment: When I look at the commands I sent to enter the cli and then go to a specific path and then enter "current" I can see it is sent correctly, but I do not get any output by sending these commands, but manually works fine. I do not know what I am doing wrong :( in my output file out.log I do se only the commands I sent but no report retrieved from the server

Comment: let me see if i understand you correctly, now the script works but you dont see the output ? have you tried `ansible expect_module` , I have updated my question.

Comment: Hi Berlin. Thank you for your feedback, I have tried to test directly (without ansible) on the server without login to bwcli and I dont get no output. I have tried sending a basic command " ll ls" but no output of this. So I have decided to go an look at expect tutorial as I am sure that the problem is manily in my lack of understanding of how expect works. I will you update it if I have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must consider that when in the BroadWorks CLI, the 'cd' command acts similarly to the equivalent shell command to navigate from one CLI context to the other. However, I'm not sure there is a root as in 'send "cd /Monitoring/Report"\r'.
To get back in the root of the CLI, you could use: 'send "qa; cd Monitoring/Report;"\r' instead.
Furthermore to verify that you moved to the right CLI context, you might want to ' expect "Monitoring/Report>"' intead of '>'.
Note that expect could be used to define functions.

Comment: Hi Francozen, thank you for your feedback, I have tried to test directly (without ansible) on the server without login to bwcli and I dont get no output. I have tried sending a basic command " ll ls" but no output of this. So I have decided to go an look at expect tutorial as I am sure that the problem is manily in my lack of understanding of how expect works. I will you update it if I have solved the problem.

Comment: Hello, I got it to work now it was simple than I expected :)  
#!/usr/bin/expect

# This will set a timeout for each send command sent to remote server
set timeout 5

spawn  bash


send "bwcli\r"

expect "AS_CLI>"


send "l admin\r"

expect "Password:"

send "Mypassword\r"

expect "AS_CLI>"
# Those are 5 commands in oneline
send "qbw;3;0;7;2\r"
expect eof

Comment: First this shell script runs fine localy without ansible and I get the output I expect. But When I run it with Ansible I can see that I logged in and the output is full of this "":  
            =============================", 
        "", 
        "BroadWorks Command Line Interface", 
        "", 
        "  Type HELP for more information", 
        "",            "======================================================================", 
        "", 
        "Reading initial CLI command file...", 
        "", 
        "\u001b[?1h", 
        "", 
        "", 
        ""

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I found that you need to run the `bwcli` command with the `-nobash` option.

Playbook:

```yaml
- name: Play 1                                                                                               
  hosts: mediaservers                                                                                         
  tasks:                                                                                                      
  - name: Play - 1 change to bwcli using script                                                               
    script: /etc/ansible/bwcli.sh                                                                             
    args:                                                                                                     
      executable: /usr/bin/expect                                                                             
    register: bwcli_output
  - debug: var=bwcli_output
```

Expect Script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
# This will set a timeout for each send command sent to remote server
set timeout 20
spawn bash
send "bwcli -nobash\r";
expect "*_CLI*"
send "int;snmp;v3u\r"
expect "*V3Users*"
send "delete bwems\r"
expect "*Warning: The SNMP Agent needs to be restarted*"
send "get\r"
expect "*_CLI*"
send "exit\r"
expect "*Yes*\r"
send "Yes\r"
expect eof
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please have a look at the edit so you know how to format your code correctly for next answers/questions. Thanks.